# Eclipselink not persisting set field on commit

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have two objects, ObjectA

```
class ObjectA
{
    Long id;
    ObjectB b;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = ObjectB.class, mappedBy = "a")
    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECTB_ID")
    public ObjectB getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public void setB(ObjectB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "OBJECTA_SEQ", sequenceName = "OBJECTA_SEQ", allocationSize = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "OBJECTA_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id= id;
    }
}
```

and ObjectB

```
class ObjectB
{
    Long id;
    ObjectA a;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, targetEntity = ObjectA.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECTA_ID", referencedColumnName = "OBJECTA_ID", nullable = false)
    public ObjectA getA() {
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public void setA(ObjectA a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
     @Override
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "OBJECTB_SEQ", sequenceName = "OBJECTB_SEQ", allocationSize = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "OBJECTB_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id= id;
    }
}
```

When I set `ObjectA.b` and `ObjectB.a` and persist, what occurs is in the database `OBJECTB.OBJECTA_ID` gets set, but `OBJECTA.OBJECTB_ID` does not get set, so `ObjectB` is not associated with `ObjectA`, but `ObjectA`'s association with `ObjectB` is not set. Looking at the SQL statements EclipseLink makes, the update statement for `ObjectA` ends up looking like

```
INSERT INTO OBJECTA (ID) VALUES....
```

ignoring the field `OBJECTB_ID` which would explain why it's not being set. I'm assuming this is due to how I set up the annotations. What is the issue with my annotation set up that is causing this to occur?

Comment: so post your ACTUAL persistence code, with transaction details etc. PS A CLASS shouldn't really be called ObjectX ... An OBJECT is an instance of a CLASS.

Comment: You have a circular foreign key.  A's OBJECTB_ID field requires a row in B is inserted before it can be set, while B's OBJECTA_ID requires a row in A before it can be set.  If you are pointing them at the same instances, there is no way they can both be completely inserted in a single statement - one of the foreign keys will have to be left null and updated later.  That is assuming you set the relationship on both instances.